# Calculating the time complexity of a python function

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity

Hey I am a private tutor in Python for students in the "Intro to CS" class in a nearby university. My student gave me a question from a test about calculating the time complexity (Big O Notation) of some function, and I am having a hard time myself coming up with a good answer and explanation to how I got it.
This is the function:

```
def oh(lst, n):
    if n==1:
        print(lst)
        return
    for i in range(n):
        oh(lst, n-1)
        if n%2==0:
            lst[i], lst[n-1] = lst[n-1], lst[i]
        else:
            lst[0], lst[n-1] = lst[n-1], lst[0]
```

Now the way I see it, it's supposed to be something along the lines of n**(n-1) or something big like that, since every recursive call makes n calls to the next recursion, I tested the function with a wrapper to see how it runs for n=10 and some lst with 10 ints, and count the operations manually and got something that vaguely fits my assumption (about 15 million operations), but it's not precise enough..

Comment: Your estimate looks good to me. I'm not sure what's the purpose of this function, but it has the worst time complexity I've seen so far.

Comment: it appears to be some sort of attempt at a bubble sort, which is O(n^2) which is what this looks like

Comment: @gold_cy: this is most definitely not n^2, though :)

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the complexity appears to be O(n!). With a list of 5 elements, we will do 5 passes of `oh(lst, 4)`, each of which will do 4 passes of `oh(lst, 3)` and so on.

Comment: agree with sergio on this one. the recursive call is inside a loop of `range(n)`, where `n` decreases by 1 with each recursive call. looks to be _O(n!)_

Comment: Thanks all!
O(n!) seems to make sense but when I actually count the number of operations on an input (wrapped the function in some code that will count the number of iterations in the for-loop - only the for loop cause it's a good measure for the overall O notation, and not the actual num of operations), I get numbers larger than factorial but in a weird way.

I made a loop running this functions with input lengths from 2-11 (this is a shitty one so running with larger inputs take too much time), the ratio starts at 1-1 and grows a bit until it settles at 1-1.71 for inputs of lengths 6-10.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sadly that's a question from their final test in the "Intro to CS" course (The Hebrew University in Jerusalem if it matters). For some reason they tend to test students with questions about reading abysmal code, and rarely test them on writing better code (naming variables, choosing less convoluted paths to a solution, meaningfully debugging code etc.), they teach how to choose correct data structures for arrays in more advanced classes, but not really with practicality in mind. Hopefully other universities around the world make more sense of things

Comment: @NadavPorat I rewrote this in ruby and in my tests I get exactly `n!` number of iterations (I increment iterations in the terminal condition `if n == 1`)

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n
```

Where `T(n)` is time taken for input list of size n

This gives `O(n!)` time complexity. If you expand the relation above, you will get a more precise answer, but the complexity will be `O(n!)`